# Can Obfuscate be targeted?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

Can a vampire decide whether Obfuscate does or does not affect everyone in the room? For example, perhaps the party knows that their mekhet is hiding in the corner and they can see him but the enemy cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no provision for that in the power. If you want to be immune to someone's Obfuscate, you've got to break it "through Auspex, attack, or other means." On the other hand, it sounds like it'd make for a good Devotion.